# flutter: FormatException: Unterminated string while decoding long stream response

Tags: json, flutter, dart, server-sent-events

I was working on a flutter package that I made https://github.com/pratikbaid3/flutter_client_sse. This is used to consume server-sent events. This works fine when the response returned is comparatively small. But as soon as the response grows large, I start getting this error `flutter: FormatException: Unterminated string`

This is the code snippet used to get the sse

```
    while (true) {
      try {
        _client = http.Client();
        var request = new http.Request("GET", Uri.parse(url));
        request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
        request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";
        request.headers["Cookie"] = token;
        Future<http.StreamedResponse> response = _client.send(request);
        await for (final data in response.asStream()) {
          await for (final d in data.stream) {
            final rawData = utf8.decode(d);
            final event = rawData.split("\n")[1];
            if (event != null && event != '') {
              yield SSEModel.fromData(rawData);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('---ERROR---');
        print(e);
        yield SSEModel(data: '', id: '', event: '');
      }
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {});
    }
```

My guess is that a part of the response is lost due to the large size.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  I would suggest: 1. Narrow down where the exception is coming from.  You should not discard the stack trace that accompanies the thrown exception. 2. Narrow down conditions for the exception to occur.  Does it always occur for responses of a certain length?  If so, what is that length?  Have you tried examining the response that triggers the failure?  Could the failure be caused by processing individual chunks from the response? (For example, is it guaranteed that chunks are split on UTF-8 codepoint boundaries?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of debugging, I found that in my current approach when the response is ***very large***, part of it is *truncated* (Not sure why). I changed the code to read one line at a time and got it to work.

```dart
            data.stream
            ..transform(Utf8Decoder())
                .transform(LineSplitter())
                .listen((dataLine) {
                     //Do what you want with the data here
                 }
```

This seemed to solve the issue.
The complete code can be found at https://github.com/pratikbaid3/flutter_client_sse